# How to layout elements in UIView set to landscape mode

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am developing an iOS app with a landscape-only layout.

When laying out elements in Storyboard, I set the orientation in 'Simulated metrics' of the only `UIViewController` I have in landscape mode.

For example, I have this `UIViewController`/`UIView` in my `Storyboard

[image: Screenshot]`

However, when I run the app on my phone the segmented controller is never in the correct position. If I add several constraints:

[image]

the segmented controls are distorted in various ways but they never appear as in the Storyboard editor.

Any help?

This is how it appears.

[image]

---

After removing the segmented control, I added a new one and used 'reset to suggested coinstraints'. The segmented control is shown in portrait mode in a UIViewController set to landscape - as shown by the status bar. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think most of us have a love/hate relationship with autolayout. Looking at your screenshot, it looks like a bunch of conflicting constraints are at work.

One thing you might try is the "resolve autolayout constraints" option (on the segmented controller in the storyboard...;). (this assumes xcode 5).

When I'm confused about layout constraints, I like to start by clearing constraints. I would then give "reset to suggested constraints" a try too. This lets xcode automatically compute some constraints for you. It's not 100% perfect, but usually gets you close.

Comment: Why are the constraints conflicting?

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe you put in a few constraints, then repositioned the segmented controls without updating the constraints. The distortion might come from autolayout adhering to constraints w,x,y,z but then resizing the controls in order to maintain w,x,y,z. The solution is to delete all the constraints and add the minimum you need to achieve the desired position. (Technically, in order to achieve the positioning in your diagram, you just need two constraints, not 4.)

Comment: I followed your suggestion and only two constraints were kept. However, the view is still wrong. I added a picture showing the final result on an iPhone.

Comment: try clearing both constraints, and then use "reset to suggested constraints". (I'm able to do this without incident on a clean project.)

Comment: Final piece of advice about constraints. Don't be afraid to blow them up and reset them as needed. Once you do it enough times, you'll get a better feel for how autolayout constraints work. :)

Comment: I removed the segmented control, added a new one and used "reset to suggested constraints". The problem is that the segmented control are shown in portrait mode, even if added to a UIViewController set to landscape, both in Storyboard and in code. How did you manage to have the segmented control in landscape?

Comment: I even deleted the Storyboard and prepared a new one. Nothing changes.

Comment: Check the project navigator -> General -> Deployment info -> Device Orientation. Is landscape left/right checked?

Comment: The other silly thing. Did you set rotation lock on your iphone? (I've done this more than one time :)

Comment: Yes. Device orientation is set to landscape and the phone has not set the rotation lock. It's a mystery.

Comment: Weird. Anything in appdelegate.m or the viewcontroller.m? Otherwise, just to rule out everything, have you tried just starting a new project?

Comment: This is my second project. I really cannot understand what is happening (I touched the appdelegate only having it to use the storyboard).